# Send C++ code in SOAP request

Tags: xml, soap, encoding, xsd

I am trying to get some code snippet compiled using Ideone.com's SOAP API. For that I have to send the source-code in a SOAP request. Here is the specification for that SOAP request:

```
<message name="createSubmissionIn">
<part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="pass" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="sourceCode" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="language" type="xsd:int"/>
<part name="input" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="run" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<part name="private" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</message>
```

As mentioned, the `sourceCode` is supposed to be a string, while the code is a 'text'. 
Take, for example the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello Ideone!";
    return 0;
}
```

If I `encodeURIComponent` it in javascript client before sending the request (as mentioned somewhere else), the resulting text is:

`%23include%20%0A%0Ausing%20namespace%20std%3B%0A%0Aint%20main()%0A%7B%0A%09cout%3C%3C%22Hello%20Ideone!%22%3B%0A%09return%200%3B%0A%7D`

which is being deferred as invalid code (compilation error). I confirmed the code received at server and the code is not being decoded at the server side. 
If I send it as a single line, then the compilation error is still there as you cant have rest of the code in `#include` line.
I tried the CDATA thing also, but dint do anything.

So, please guide me through this problem. How to send the code snippet successfully in the SOAP request.

P.S. Just in case my client might be bad-designed, I am using online SOAP client:
http://soapclient.com/soapclient?template=%2Fclientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=%2FSoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=http%3A%2F%2Fideone.com%2Fapi%2F1%2Fservice.wsdl&_ArraySize=5

Answer (score 0):

Today, it seems like thier API may be broken.  A demo python client is provided here.
http://ideone.com/files/python-test/ideone.py However, it is failing with an authentication error.  So, in order to attempt to answer your question, I wrote these two mini Perl programs.

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use SOAP::Lite;

my ($user, $pass, $source, $lang, $input, $run, $private);

$user = "FRED";
$pass = "PASS";
$lang=1;
$source = <<CODEDOC;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"Hello Ideone!";
return 0;
}
CODEDOC
$input="INPUT";
$run=0;
$private=0;

print SOAP::Lite                                            
-> proxy('http://localhost/cgi-bin/code_demo.pl')
-> uri('http://localhost/CodeDemo')                                    
-> code($user, $pass, $source, $lang, $input, $run, private)                                             
-> result;
```

**Sever (CGI)**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI   
-> dispatch_to('CodeDemo')     
-> handle;

package CodeDemo;

sub code{
    my ($self, $user, $pass, $source, $lang, $input, $run, $private) = @_;
    my $retval ;
    $retval = sprintf("User:%s\nPass:%s\nSource:%s\nLang:%s\nInput:%s\nRun:%s\nPrivate:%s\n",
        $user, $pass, $source, $lang, $input, $run, $private);
    return $retval;
}
```

This seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: No, the API is not broken. Right now, I have to use a PHP proxy to connect with their API. It is working absolutely fine. (PHP uses '\n' as the new line feed for encoding the text to a string.) But when I try it directly using xhr, it just doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 0):

No Problem.  Here is a working and tested PHP version.  I actually tested this and uploaded code using the service.  I did notice that I needed to update my profile even though I set my API password during the creation of my account.

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl');

$user = "VALID_USER_NAME";
$pass = "VALID_PASSWORD";
$lang=1;
$source = <<<CODEDOC
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"Hello Ideone!";
return 0;
}
CODEDOC;
$input="INPUT";
$run=0;
$private=0;

print_r($client->createSubmission($user, $pass, $source, $lang, $input, $run, $private));
?>
```

Comment: that's only what i am using as a workaround but my issue is not this. it is working but i want to remove the php proxy and call the soap api using xhr directly.